# Parsing nested json in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following json where there can be multiple vehicles and each vehicle can contain multiple trips. I need to insert vehicles in to the `TVHC` table and for each vehicle insert trips into TTRP table.

```
[
  {
    "VHC_VTY_CDE": "CAR", 
    "VHC_NAT_CDE": "USA", 
    "VHC_MAN_YEAR": "2020",         
    "VHC_PLT_NBR": "ABC123", 
    "VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE": "USA",
    "VHC_STA_ID": "1",
    "VHC_STA_CDE": "P",
    "VHC_COL_CDE":"",
    "Trips":[
        {
            "TRP_DTE":"2024-01-30",
            "TRP_TIME":"12:00:00.0000000",
            "TRP_BRD_CDE":"061",
            "TRP_AIR_CDE":"QTR",
            "TRP_SHP_CDE":"S12",
            "TRP_FGT_NBR":"CargoXYZ",
            "TRP_SHP_NBR":"S12"
        },
        {
            "TRP_DTE":"2024-01-30",
            "TRP_TIME":"12:00:00.0000000",
            "TRP_BRD_CDE":"061",
            "TRP_AIR_CDE":"QTR",
            "TRP_SHP_CDE":"S12",
            "TRP_FGT_NBR":"CargoXYZ",
            "TRP_SHP_NBR":"S12"
        }
    ]
  }
]
```

I am using the following procedure to insert the data but I'm getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure Usama_Test, Line 81 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Incorrect syntax near ')'

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertVehicles]
    @vehicles_trips_json NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @TRV_ID AS BIGINT
AS
--BEGIN TRANSACTION

    INSERT INTO TVHC 
        (
            VHC_TRV_ID,
            VHC_VTY_CDE,            
            VHC_NAT_CDE,
            VHC_MAN_YEAR,
            VHC_PLT_NBR,
            VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE,
            VHC_STY_ID,
            VHC_STA_CDE,
            VHC_COL_CDE         
        )
        
        SELECT  
                @TRV_ID,
                VHC_VTY_CDE,
                VHC_NAT_CDE,
                VHC_MAN_YEAR,
                VHC_PLT_NBR,
                VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE,
                VHC_STY_ID,
                VHC_STA_CDE,
                VHC_COL_CDE
            FROM
                OPENJSON(@vehicles_trips_json)
                WITH (  
                     [VHC_VTY_CDE]   char(3) N'$.VHC_VTY_CDE',
                     [VHC_NAT_CDE]   char(3) N'$.VHC_NAT_CDE',
                     [VHC_MAN_YEAR]   char(4) N'$.VHC_MAN_YEAR',
                     [VHC_PLT_NBR]   varchar(20) N'$.VHC_PLT_NBR',
                     [VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE]      char(3) N'$.VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE',
                     [VHC_STY_ID]   int N'$.VHC_STY_ID',
                     [VHC_STA_CDE]      int N'$.VHC_STA_CDE',
                     [VHC_COL_CDE]   char(10) N'$.VHC_COL_CDE',
                     [Trips]   nvarchar(max) N'$.Trips'
                    ) AS ROOT_JSON

                OUTER APPLY
                (
                    INSERT INTO TTRP 
                    (
                        TRP_DTE,
                        TRP_TIME,
                        TRP_VHC_ID,
                        TRP_BRD_CDE,
                        TRP_AIR_CDE,
                        TRP_SHP_CDE,
                        TRP_FGT_NBR,
                        TRP_SHP_NBR
                    )
                
                    SELECT  
                            TRP_DTE,
                            TRP_TIME,
                            @@IDENTITY,
                            TRP_BRD_CDE,
                            TRP_AIR_CDE,
                            TRP_SHP_CDE,
                            TRP_FGT_NBR,
                            TRP_SHP_NBR
                        FROM
                            OPENJSON(ROOT_JSON.Trips)
                            WITH (  
                                 [TRP_DTE]   date N'$.TRP_DTE',
                                 [TRP_TIME]   time(7) N'$.TRP_TIME',
                                 [TRP_BRD_CDE]   char(3) N'$.TRP_BRD_CDE',
                                 [TRP_AIR_CDE]   char(3) N'$.TRP_AIR_CDE',
                                 [TRP_SHP_CDE]      char(3) N'$.TRP_SHP_CDE',
                                 [TRP_FGT_NBR]      varchar(20) N'$.TRP_FGT_NBR',
                                 [TRP_SHP_NBR]   varchar(20) N'$.TRP_SHP_NBR'
                                ) 
                )   
--COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Any ideas??

It's a syntax error and I tried multiple variations but didn't work.

https://www.codelabs365.com/sql-cookbook/sql-server/tsql-examples-parse-nested-json-with-openjson-function-using-cross-apply-techniques/

Comment: Is the outer JSON array going to have multiple objects or always exactly one? If so do they have unique IDs?

Comment: Does the JSON contain some kind of primary key for cars? Can we assume that `(VHC_PLT_NBR, VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE)` cold be used to identify cars uniquely?

Comment: @Charlieface In the request json there can be mutiple vehicles (TVHC) and each vehicle may contain multiple trips (TTRP).

Comment: @SalmanA Vehicle table (TVHC) has identity column VHC_ID however we can also identify a vehicle uniquely with VHC_PLT_NBR.

Comment: @usama then you can do it in two steps (wrapped in a transaction). In step 1 you insert into vehicles table including VHC_PLT_NBR. In step 2 you insert into trips, when inserting, look up the identity column like `insert into trips (..., TRP_VHC_ID) select ..., (select VHC_ID from vehicles where vehicles.VHC_PLT_NBR = data_from_json.VHC_PLT_NBR)`

Comment: Above comment assuming that you have multiple vehicles in your json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't put an `INSERT` inside another `INSERT` (except in certain situations using an `OUTPUT` clause).

Instead you need to use a separate statement and break out the JSON again.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertVehicles]
  @vehicles_trips_json NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @TRV_ID AS BIGINT
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

INSERT INTO TVHC 
(
  VHC_TRV_ID,
  VHC_VTY_CDE,            
  VHC_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_MAN_YEAR,
  VHC_PLT_NBR,
  VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_STY_ID,
  VHC_STA_CDE,
  VHC_COL_CDE         
)
SELECT  
  @TRV_ID,
  VHC_VTY_CDE,
  VHC_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_MAN_YEAR,
  VHC_PLT_NBR,
  VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_STY_ID,
  VHC_STA_CDE,
  VHC_COL_CDE
FROM
  OPENJSON(@vehicles_trips_json)
  WITH (  
    VHC_VTY_CDE char(3),
    VHC_NAT_CDE char(3),
    VHC_MAN_YEAR char(4),
    VHC_PLT_NBR varchar(20),
    VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE char(3),
    VHC_STY_ID int,
    VHC_STA_CDE int,
    VHC_COL_CDE char(10)
  ) AS ROOT_JSON;

DECLARE @id int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

INSERT INTO TTRP 
(
  TRP_DTE,
  TRP_TIME,
  TRP_VHC_ID,
  TRP_BRD_CDE,
  TRP_AIR_CDE,
  TRP_SHP_CDE,
  TRP_FGT_NBR,
  TRP_SHP_NBR
)
SELECT  
  TRP_DTE,
  TRP_TIME,
  @id,
  TRP_BRD_CDE,
  TRP_AIR_CDE,
  TRP_SHP_CDE,
  TRP_FGT_NBR,
  TRP_SHP_NBR
FROM
  OPENJSON(@vehicles_trips_json, N'$[0].Trips')
  WITH (  
    TRP_DTE   date,
    TRP_TIME   time(7),
    TRP_BRD_CDE   char(3),
    TRP_AIR_CDE   char(3),
    TRP_SHP_CDE   char(3),
    TRP_FGT_NBR   varchar(20),
    TRP_SHP_NBR   varchar(20)
  );

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` not `@@IDENTITY`. If there are multiple outer array objects then it gets more complicated, as you need to use an `OUTPUT` clause into a table variable to capture the Identity values along with some kind of identifier.

But you probably need the `MERGE` trick in order to get `OUTPUT` working.

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[insertVehicles]
  @vehicles_trips_json NVARCHAR(MAX),
  @TRV_ID AS BIGINT
AS

SET NOCOUNT, XACT_ABORT ON;

BEGIN TRAN;

DECLARE @trips TABLE (id int PRIMARY KEY, trips nvarchar(max));

WITH ROOT_JSON AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM
    OPENJSON(@vehicles_trips_json)
    WITH (  
      VHC_VTY_CDE char(3),
      VHC_NAT_CDE char(3),
      VHC_MAN_YEAR char(4),
      VHC_PLT_NBR varchar(20),
      VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE char(3),
      VHC_STY_ID int,
      VHC_STA_CDE int,
      VHC_COL_CDE char(10),
      Trips nvarchar(max) AS JSON
    ) AS ROOT_JSON
)
MERGE TVHC
USING ROOT_JSON
ON 1=0    --never match
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN INSERT
(
  VHC_TRV_ID,
  VHC_VTY_CDE,            
  VHC_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_MAN_YEAR,
  VHC_PLT_NBR,
  VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_STY_ID,
  VHC_STA_CDE,
  VHC_COL_CDE         
)
VALUES (
  @TRV_ID,
  VHC_VTY_CDE,
  VHC_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_MAN_YEAR,
  VHC_PLT_NBR,
  VHC_PLT_NAT_CDE,
  VHC_STY_ID,
  VHC_STA_CDE,
  VHC_COL_CDE
)
OUTPUT inserted.VHC_ID, ROOT_JSON.Trips
INTO @trips (id, trips);

INSERT INTO TTRP 
(
  TRP_DTE,
  TRP_TIME,
  TRP_VHC_ID,
  TRP_BRD_CDE,
  TRP_AIR_CDE,
  TRP_SHP_CDE,
  TRP_FGT_NBR,
  TRP_SHP_NBR
)
SELECT  
  j.TRP_DTE,
  j.TRP_TIME,
  t.id,
  j.TRP_BRD_CDE,
  j.TRP_AIR_CDE,
  j.TRP_SHP_CDE,
  j.TRP_FGT_NBR,
  j.TRP_SHP_NBR
FROM
  @trips t
CROSS APPLY
  OPENJSON(t.Trips)
  WITH (  
    TRP_DTE   date,
    TRP_TIME   time(7),
    TRP_BRD_CDE   char(3),
    TRP_AIR_CDE   char(3),
    TRP_SHP_CDE   char(3),
    TRP_FGT_NBR   varchar(20),
    TRP_SHP_NBR   varchar(20)
  ) j;

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am getting "The multi-part identifier "ROOT_JSON.Trips" could not be bound." error when trying to create this procedure.

Comment: Sorry copy-paste error

Comment: Thanks for your help. The procedure works perfect.